# ProGuard duplicate zip entry issue

Tags: android, proguard

I'm building android tv application based on leanback library. Leanback library has a lot of restrictions to enhance functionality. And I copied all needed classes from leanback to my application (moved it to android.support.v17.leanback package) with some modifications. So it means this classes will override the same classes from leanback. It works fine. But when I try to use proguard to obfuscate the application I get an error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForMyApp_prodRelease_signed'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [I:\Projects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\myapp_prod\release_signed\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [I:\Projects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\classes\myapp_prod\release_signed(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v17/leanback/app/BaseFragment$1.class]))
```

I understand that during the obfuscation proguard finds 2 duplicates of the same class. Can proguard ignore one of them and finish obfuscation without any error?